# Is explorer.exe connecting to a Singapore Microsoft server common behaviour?

Tags: windows, netstat

Netstas results

explorer.exe TCP 192.168.x.x: 491x 111.221.124.116: 443 ESTABLISHED

Is this part of error reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 443 is the `https`-protocol. Depending on your Windows-version and settings it could be part of SmartScreen.

Why would you think it was part of the "error reporting"?
Error reporting would only occur **when** you encounter an error. And even then Microsoft asks permission to send data to its servers.

So i think SmartScreen is a more likely candidate for this open connection.
SmartScreen is used to scans all the files before opening them. This protects you from malware.

[image]

You can read a discussion [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58f4c838-0fc4-4ac2-8bd7-c96716980736/explorerexe-opening-up-http-connections-back-to-ms?forum=w8itprogeneral). It's a different IP but i imagine Microsoft uses many different IPs for this.

If you want to disable SmartScreen (to see if it is indeed the connection you're referring to)
you can follow [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/75356/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-the-smartscreen-filter-in-windows-8/) (if you use Windows 8).

[image]

Comment: I agree.  Had mentioned about error reporting because that one thing I had on top of mind - that would need to connect to server.  SmartScreen does seem to be more likely.  Thanks